# HandlerThread didn't run in background?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I'm trying to learn how to use HandlerThread to run things in background. I have a button in a fragment that when clicked, I want to get the number of entries from a database. But when I actually run it, logcat says the application may be doing too much work on the main thread, and I don't know what I did wrong.

Here's how I arranged my code in the fragment:

```java
private Handler handler=new Handler();
private MyWorkerThread myWorkerThread;

private Runnable myRunnable=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Item> list=db.getAllItems();
                Log.d(TAG,"Size: "+list.size());
            }
        });
    }
};

private class MyWorkerThread extends HandlerThread{
    private Handler myHandler;

    private MyWorkerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    private void postTask(Runnable task){
        myHandler.post(task);
    }

    private void setMyHandler(){
        myHandler=new Handler(getLooper());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myWorkerThread=new MyWorkerThread("myWorkerThread");
    myWorkerThread.start();
    myWorkerThread.setMyHandler();
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn)
void getCount(){
    myWorkerThread.postTask(myRunnable);
}
```

I'm following the example in [this blog post](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/), but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and it still blocks the UI while running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this from your `Runnable`:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
```

You are posting your `Runnable` which in turn just posts a `Runnable` back to the main thread. So your main thread is still doing all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify runnable like this:-

```
private Runnable myRunnable=new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
      List<Item> list=db.getAllItems();
      Log.d(TAG,"Size: "+list.size());
}};
```

Comment: @Scratte- yes, you just need to modify runnable like this and post runnable to handlerthread

Comment: Yes :) Removing `handler.post(new Runnable() {` will result in the code you presented. Please be aware that posting an almost identical answer may result in down votes.

Comment: I think it provides more clarity than the previous answer